# What to do when you spot a paper on arXiv with the same essential material as yours?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, arxiv

What do you do when you've sent a paper on your fancy new algorithm to a conference, and before the conference has replied to you, you spot a newly submitted paper on arXiv on the same algorithm?

Possible reactions I can imagine:

1. You immediately submit your work to arXiv and/or open-source your code to "prove" you were working on it too (or at least as much as that might be worth at this point)
2. You just wait and see if the conference accepts it (but then what?)
3. You withdraw your paper entirely -- you "lost"
4. You totally ignore it -- it's not "official" until it's peer-reviewed, so you might still be "first"

Furthermore, who typically gets credit if:

1. Your paper is accepted, and is first to be published outside of arXiv
2. Your paper is declined, and is *not* first to be published outside of arXiv

---

#### Update

I'm reading the other group's paper more carefully (I'd only had a chance to glance at it yesterday, and was alarmed because several of the key words and concepts were exactly the same as ours), and it seems like they might not have discovered the same algorithm after all -- it's difficult for me to tell because their notation and terminology varies considerably from ours, but there's a chance that we've found different algorithms, even though several key concepts are the same. I'll continue looking into it, but just thought I'd mention this to add more context. At least now I'm a little bit more hopeful.

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect that your work was stolen, or does it seem to simply be a case of simultaneous invention?

Comment: I'll relate a similar recent occurrence from last year in physics: A theoretical paper came out suggesting a new phenomenon. Inspired by this, two research groups ran numerical simulations to probe for the phenomenon and uploaded their results on arXiv. They were four days apart. One of the groups later acknowledged the others' preprint: "At the time of writing this paper, we became aware of a pre-print ... have reached similar conclusions as us." Both got later published in journals. I think uploading to arXiv does get you more visibility especially in case your paper is indeed rejected.

Comment: Do you consider contacting people who (re)-produce the same algorithm? Conferences and publications are means to facilitate the communication between researchers, not the opposite.

Comment: @Moriarty: No, it's almost certainly simultaneous invention, nothing malicious going on.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov: That may be a possibility, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Weep. [‌](http://longer)

Comment: @Lodewijk: Yeah, I'm already doing that...

Comment: It happened to me once, when I co-authored a `hep-th` paper on arXiv the Thursday before Easter. The next Monday, another group published essentially the same paper. On Tuesday, our group did celebrate this event with a round of cake for everyone at our institute :-) The other group had a note in their paper, acknowledging our contribution, and in a second version, we put added a note acknowledging their results.

Comment: My advisor was once on the receiving end. He arrived at an informal conference where he and another person in his parallel session both still had to submit their titles (they both were TBA in the program). When he submitted his title, he discovered it was the same as the talk just prior to him. To make it worse: the other group had submitted their talk on arXiv that day. This was on a national holiday in our country, with noone of his collaborators reachable. I think he submitted their work-in-progess within a week after the conference. In the end both papers ended up acknowledging each other.

Comment: Anyway, in some fields this happens quite often. I used to be active in the string theory subfield of `hep-th`, and this used to be quite a fad-driven topic, and simultaneous discoveries were quite common.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It seems to me that the best answer is some combination of 1. and 2.  Because you submitted the paper for review before the other work -- call it paper X -- appeared on the arxiv, the community will readily believe that your work does not rely on paper X.  (At first I wrote "completely clear that your work does not rely", but that's too strong: it's possible that you had some prior contact with the authors of paper X and learned about their work before it was published.  But from your description that didn't actually happen, so no problem there.)

So you are in a fortunate situation: because you submitted the work to the conference before the arxiv posting, you have established your independent priority.  The fact that the report hasn't come back yet has nothing to do with that.  With respect to the submission, it would be reasonable to just wait for the report -- I am assuming that since it is a conference, it will come back within a month or so?  If your paper is accepted, then you should include in the published version and also in your conference talk the information that similar (or the same...) work was independently done in paper X.

However it would be a good idea to write immediately to the authors of paper X and let them know about your work.  If you are in a field where the conference paper will be supplemented by a later journal paper, then depending upon the degree of similarity you may want to consider a joint publication.  If not, then your journal papers should cocite each other: this establishes that "you both have priority", which is certainly possible, and then both works should be publishable.  (But in my opinion a joint paper is the better option if the work is very similar: does the community need two versions of the same work?  Can everyone be counted on to know about and value the two works equally?  Better to join forces: that seals it.)  Depending upon the response you receive and the timing it might be a good idea to post your submission to the arxiv as well, with a note explaining the chronology.

I disagree with both 3. and 4.  First, it does not matter who did the work chronologically first but rather that each work was done independently and before the other was *published*.  **There does not need to be a "winner" and a "loser" here: you can both "win".**  It is good that research communities operate in this way, much better than your option 4.: no one has control over which referee report comes back first or which paper goes to press first or anything like that, so if this were the standard it would be at the very least quite unfair and in fact open to all kinds of ethical issues and abuses.

**Note**: One of the comments asks whether the work was stolen.  It seems that the only plausible way for this to happen is for there to be some collusion between the authors of paper X and either the conference organizers or the chosen referees of your paper.  This type of behavior is in my experience extremely rare, so I don't want to address it in my answer.

Comment: +1 for emphasizing that this is not a zero sum game with winners and losers.

Comment: Yeah the conference results will come back soon. One thing that complicates things is that they don't take the submissions and publish them directly -- they will ask for a final revision if they accept the paper, which means the PDF won't be timestamped because it'll be different from the one submitted earlier. Would that matter at all? And what happens if it gets rejected?

Comment: @Mehrdad: You should include the citation of the other result in any revisions you make, with language that describes the chronology of the situation (e.g. "After this paper was submitted, we learned...").  You don't need timestamped PDFs because you showed your document to actual people before the other work became available.  I would be very surprised if the editors did not keep copies of all the submitted versions; indubitably they will keep the record of when you submitted.

Comment: If the paper gets rejected then you can still ensure your priority by including in your next version information about when and where you submitted it, which the editors will certainly be able to corroborate.  However I reiterate that contacting the other authors ASAP would be a very good idea: if *they agree* that your work was independently done there is really no problem here.  If you feel at all nervous about arriving at such an agreement,  @Mangara's advice to immediately upload your paper to the arxiv seems good.  In general, do that whenever you feel the first pangs of "scoop-worry"!

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I don't quite understand why I need to cite the other result though. Citing the results implicitly acknowledges that our work came "after" theirs and give them some credit for being first, whereas in reality I have no reason to believe they did any of this first -- only that they put it on arXiv before we did. I will definitely try to contact them though -- I don't expect they'll disagree this was independent work. Thanks for the advice. +1

Comment: @Mehrdad: I do not agree that you only cite work that comes before yours.  You also cite work which was done at approximately the same time, if you know about it in time to do so; that's what I meant by "cociting".  You seem to be acting as if you don't want to cede the advantage of your work being chronologically first (if in fact it was -- who knows?  what does that even mean, really?).  I am suggesting that you regard the situation as symmetric between you and the other party: wouldn't you want it that way if the roles were reversed?

Comment: Another reason to cocite is the obligation of academic honesty: you need to draw the reader's attention to all related work of which you're aware.  Sometimes your awareness changes in the course of the publication/revision process, in which case you do not need to (nor is it necessarily appropriate to) substantially rewrite the paper.  But you still need to inform the reader about the other work, since you now know about it.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I don't understand how the situation would be symmetric in that case, though. It's not like they cited our work in their paper, so if we cite their work they're implicitly first and we're implicitly acknowledging we're second.

Comment: @Mehrdad: They don't have a published paper; they have an arxiv preprint which they can (and should) modify.  The symmetry is that both parties should cocite each other.  Nor do you leave anything implicit: you clearly explain the chronology so the reader understands the situation.  See e.g. http://www.math.uga.edu/~pete/thuelemmav6.pdf and http://www.tcnj.edu/~hagedorn/papers/Geometry%20of%20Convenient%20Numbers.pdf: this is quite common.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Ok I guess that depends on what they say once we contact them, since I'm not planning on citing them if they're not going to cite us at the same time. Of course if they do then we will too, it wouldn't make sense otherwise. But I'm not really thinking of pushing them to. I'm curious though: what would happen if we don't cite them (and they don't cite us)? You mentioned academic honesty, but I'm not sure I understand what the "dishonesty" would be if we don't cite them - as far as I'm aware neither of us knew about each other, so I don't see why this would be a case of dishonesty.

Comment: @Mehrdad: At this point I recommend that you ask a followup question, in particular to get other opinions.  But briefly: neither of you knew about the other when you were doing the work, but you do *now*.  Uploading a paper within a few days of seeing someone else's paper and not mentioning that other paper is not being forthcoming.  You don't only mention papers that you use logically in your work; you have an obligation to inform the reader of directly relevant work.  And practically, not mentioning it all is not clarifying the situation: you leave room for misinterpretation.

Comment: @Pete: Hmm I think I'm good for now, not really feeling like I have any followup question to ask that isn't a duplicate of this one. Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: _I'm not planning on citing them if they're not going to cite us at the same time._ — Please don't play that game. If I reviewed your submission and was aware of the arXiv preprint, I would insist on your citing them as a condition of acceptance, no matter what the other authors did.

Comment: @JeffE: It's easy to tell people to give away credit for their hard work when it's not your own. I would find that quite unreasonable, but I would have few choices then. The situation is symmetric in my view. Barring an event like that, I'm not convinced I should cite a paper in a pre-print whose existence I'm only aware of because of a quick search I did long *after* I'd finished mine and already it for publication. If the readers are interested in simultaneous work they can find them the same way they found ours. I just can't justify giving *away* credit for work that is entirely mine.

Comment: Citing other people is not "giving away your work". You have admitted that others have independently achieved the same result as you. It follows that **you already know that you do not deserve sole credit for your results**. (For your actual work, yes. For the results of that work, no.) All you have to do is publicly admit what you already know.

Comment: @JeffE: Lots of problems with your quotes and your bolded text. For one thing I never said give away my "*work*"; I said give away "*credit*". I also never said I deserve credit for my "*results*", I said I deserve credit for my "*work*". I'm also *highly* bothered by your usage of the word "admit" -- whether or not you intended it, I feel it implicitly makes me look guilty. We'll definitely talk to the other group and figure it out, so don't worry. I do feel neither of us *needs* to cite the other, though we might anyway. I'm not interested in arguing about it though, so let's end it here.

Answer (score 18):

This actually happened with a paper I worked on. We handled it by:

1. Immediately submitting our own version to arXiv, including a short mention of the other paper.
2. Informing the other authors of our result, and offering to write a joint journal paper.

Submitting your own version as soon as possible strongly suggests that it was an independent discovery, especially if the presentation is completely original. It also sends a signal that you're not trying to hide anything.

By writing a joint 'final' version, both parties can share the credit. In our case, the papers had been submitted to different conferences, so we thought a joint journal version would be the most appropriate. In the end, both papers were rejected from these conferences, but the other authors were able to strengthen the original result, while we generalized it. This meant that we were able to write a very strong merged paper, which was accepted to the most important conference in the area.

Comment: +1 especially for your first point.  For some reason responding with a rapid uploading of your own document makes a convincing case for the independence of the work.  (Logically speaking this is unconvincing: I guess people think that intellectual thieves are slow and lazy rather than fast and hard-working?  It need not be the case!)

Comment: +1 I'll probably upload it soon, hopefully by tomorrow. Just have to make sure I don't make silly mistakes in the public version. Not really convinced why I would need to mention the other paper (nothing in our paper is based on anything they did) but I'll consider it.

Answer (score 4):

If your paper gets accepted in this conference, you win. The submission date is before the arxiv uploading and no one can claim you plagiarized the arxiv preprint.

If your paper gets rejected, you probably lost. In subsequent submissions you have to cite the original arxiv preprint, make extra effort and experiments to differentiate your work from theirs (by augmenting your original work) and claim that both works have reached independently to those parallel findings. Still, this lowers your work's novelty and might lead to another rejection. In that case, the other side might lost too, because your original rejection might also signify that the algorithm is not that seminal or important.

So, you should consider in what ways you can expand your work to actually provide novel content in comparison to the arxiv preprint, in case of rejection. In case of acceptance, you have nothing to worry about.

**UPDATE:** I really liked the other answers. Submitting to arxiv the OP's paper as soon as possible is probably the best thing to do. Also sharing co-authorship (in case of rejection) is of course the ethical / right thing to do and that is what the OP should do. But:

- Case 1. There is some foul play on the other side. In that case, they do not want to share co-authorship but patent / steal the idea. In that case, co-operation is not likely to happen
- Case 2. No foul play involved and the OP's paper gets rejected. The other side has already patented those results by their arxiv preprint. They may even already submitted the paper to another conference (many times that is when you upload preprints). Why would they share co-authorship? Would the OP share co-authorship if his paper got accepted? Will he include the other paper in the related work section (of course he should) in his camera ready version (in
  case of acceptance), when most of the results are identical? According to his comments he is not going to do that (when he has nothing to lose by that if his paper got accepted). Why does everyone assume that the other side will cooperate? These are serious questions that are easily answered on an ethical basis but the practical side is always more complicated. And what if the other side is more famous / established than the OP? Sometimes in that case they may even refuse co-authorship on that fact alone.  Co-operation and co-authorship usually happens between similar / equal parties but they are harder to achieve when the other side has more leverage.

I really hope things work for the OP. But if his paper gets accepted he should definitely cite the other work and explain the situation in his camera ready version.

Comment: It's not about winning and losing. If the asker's paper is rejected, a joint paper with the authors of the ArXiv paper is probably on the cards.

Comment: @DavidRicherby See the updated answer. I really wish things could work the "right" way but many times unfortunately they do not.

Comment: The asker's submission of the work to a conference already establishes their share of priority, even if the paper is rejected. And I, at least, assume that the other group will co-operate because that, in my experience, is what normally happens.

Comment: @Alexandros: The OP is rather clearly a young researcher who is trying to learn what to do in this new situation.  In my opinion you are not being so helpful by assuming the worst.  This is not a Prisoner's Dilemma situation or anything like that: in this case *both parties* can establish that their work precedes the public availability of the other's, so they both have priority.  If one party openly acknowledges this and the other doesn't, then the main thing which is lost is the opportunity to engage in best practices, like consolidating common work.  I see no potential tragedy here.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I do not assume the worst. The OP even thought of withdrawing the paper (which would be a huge mistake). But it is a great possibility that the other side has already submitted to another conference. And this is something that previous answers do not address and the OP should have in mind.

Comment: @Alexandros: Yeah I've been thinking of the same thing -- I have no idea if they've submitted it to another conference or not, and I'd definitely wondered why no one had mentioned that possibility except you.

Comment: "The OP even thought of withdrawing the paper (which would be a huge mistake)." Well, he presented it as one of four choices anyway; I agree that would be the worst thing to do.  "But it is a great possibility that the other side has already submitted to another conference. And this is something that previous answers do not address and the OP should have in mind." That is also true.  In my mind this is part of what you learn by contacting the authors of paper X.  If you have each already submitted to a conference, then probably the two works should be published separately.

Comment: When I was speaking of a joint paper, I had in mind mainly a journal paper that would follow the conference paper.  (In full disclosure: in my field -- pure mathematics -- we don't have much in the way of conference papers in this sense.)  Thanks for making that explicit.  I do think however that maintaining a cheery calm is a good reaction to this question: this is very far from a truly sticky situation.

Comment: _If your paper gets accepted in this conference, you win._ — If by "win", you mean "get sole credit", this is inconsistent with my experience. Assuming both papers appear in som form at roughly the same time, you will (eventually) both get credit, as you should.

Comment: @JeffE By winning, I mean the OP gets credit for his work. Otherwise he will have to fight for it. I understand that for professors like you, one more publication does not mean that much, but for struggling students who need them for a PHD, it does. And any mishap like that (that happens on real life) it might mean 6 months - 1 year additional work. So, if the paper gets accepted, yes the OP wins because he gets the publication he needs.

Comment: That's a bit unfair, @Alexandros. Even though I'm not a student myself any more, I have students of my own, with publication records of their own, in whose success I am personally and materially invested. When similar things have happened to them, I've said exactly the same thing: Finish the paper, and do it right. Part of doing it right is citing your competitors. Otherwise, people will notice that you didn't, when you could/should have, and that lack of generosity/honesty will hurt you more in the long run.

Comment: @JeffE Citing the "competitor"'s work, in case of acceptance is something that I have already suggested in my answer. Also, in a similar case I assume you and your students are more happy if the paper gets accepted (before the other party's work) instead of having to negotiate co-authorship and joint papers with them.

Comment: @Alexandros Actually, no.  I'd really rather join forces.  If I were in OP's situation, I'd not only cite the arXiv authors, but also invite them to be coauthors on the _conference_ paper, assuming it's accepted and the PC agrees.

Comment: @JeffE: Joining forces is great if you have the time to spend on re-authoring a paper. I'm not sure I do. I just want to publish what I have done and move on.

Comment: Too bad. If you don't want the research community (precisely the people who will be judging your suitability for jobs later) to think you're lazy, apathetic, or intentionally negligent, finish the paper properly.

Comment: @JeffE: The more of your comments I read the more antagonistic they become. When I say I might not have the time, it quite literally means *I might not have the time*. It does *not* mean I'm "lazy" or "apathetic" or "intentionally negligent". You most certainly do *not* know what my situation is like to be justified in telling me "too bad", as though you're my adviser and I'm just a lazy student who doesn't want to finish his work. Please don't pretend to know people's limitations, motivations, and constraints when you don't.

Comment: I'm not claiming that you _are_ lazy or negligent. I'm claiming that not citing the other paper will make you _look_ lazy or negligent. The latter is much worse for your career than the former.

Answer (score 4):

Many theorems, algorithms, fundamental scientific ideas, etc bear the name of (or are attributed to) more than one person. This does not always happen because these persons worked together. Sometimes it happens because it is established that they worked on the same issue *approximately* during the same period and/or published *approximately* during the same period. An example that I can immediately give from Economics/Econometrics is in the sub-field of Stochastic Frontier Analysis: in 1977 two papers were published independently, laying the fundamentals of the field. Almost 40 years later, they are still mentioned together, when the author wants to refer to those that initiated the whole thing. These papers are

[Aigner, D., Lovell, C. A. A., & Schmidt, P. (1977). Formulation and estimation of stochastic frontier production function models. journal of Econometrics, 6(1), 21-37.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304407677900525)

and

[Meeusen, W., & Van den Broeck, J. (1977). Efficiency estimation from Cobb-Douglas production functions with composed error. International economic review, 435-444.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2525757)

Your algorithm and the other algorithm may be "cousins", and the existence of both may have positive externalities on the research and professional paths of all involved, since it makes for a more vigorous "look here!" shout to the scientific world. I would even consider *promoting*  the other paper alongside yours.

Comment: +1 for making the key point that someone else who is interested in what you are working on is **a good thing**.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: It would be a good thing if I was going to continue working on this. But I've already finished the project and want to *stop* working on it -- I was only waiting to publish the results somewhere. So if someone else becomes interested that's arguably *bad* for me because it'll take away valuable time I want to spend elsewhere; I've already spent more time on the project than I ever intended to.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Well, I'm not sure what to say about that: you did say "arguably", and you are certainly entitled to your opinion as to whether this development is good or bad.  For what it's worth I truly don't see it that way.  Alas: academia is a time-consuming business.  Also, if you're sticking with it (academia, that is), it seems hard to know whether you'll return to something or not.  Many times have I put a project or research area aside for years at a time...only to return later and take it up again.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thanks for the thumbs-up. Essentially, my answer is a subset of yours, which I just read. I must confess that lately this site emits a much more negative tone than when I first subscribed. Too many questions about allegedly questionable conduct, too many answers suggesting "attack" or "admit defeat". I am an economist and have no issue with competition or even antagonism -but what big bucks I have made in life (monetary, intellectual, emotional) was by "tricking" the competition into ...balanced cooperation -so I guess I am a bit biased on the matter.