# Is it fine to post a paper to arxiv and later change the title and add authors?

Tags: authorship, arxiv, titles

I have paper with very new contributions but it needs at least one month to finish perfectly. I am afraid that someone eat my launch and publish on the area. My advisor suggests adding the paper to Arxiv. but the title may change later. is it okay?

Also, I have just checked that changing authors when replacing a paper is technically enabled. Is it okay to add authors later?

Answer (score 10):

Arxiv is just a preprinting service which is [generally] non peer-reviewed. The whole point of publishing there is to just put your idea out there (it gives you the copyrights) and to get feedback from your peers who are eager enough to read your draft. It is very common practice to update the title and author list for final publication in a journal. I have done it personally without any problem. That being said, all authors, who will be on the final publication, should be included in the arxiv submission, and not just the first/submitting author.

Comment: I'd personally feel uncomfortable putting work out for the public, including for preprint, without appropriate authorship included. Of course things might change if additions or changes to the paper warrant changes in authorship. Can you clarify if you are talking about these sorts of changes rather than omitting authors from a first submission that belong on that submission?

Comment: @BryanKrause Oh no! I will edit and clarify. I certainly didn't mean to put only your name and don't include anyone. By updating I mean if there is any addition or changes that might come at later stage. Of course, you will and you should include all the authors involved in that paper.

Comment: But it is okay to be a draft. Since the writing needs improvement

Comment: Yes, arxiv repositories generally do not have any specific typesetting requirements. If you feel comfortable with your submission then go ahead. But I would still recommend make it look a bit nicer because you will be putting it out in public.

Answer (score 7):

Neither change is against arXiv's rules. The title is often changed during the review/publishing process anyway, and arXiv supports that. Adding authors [also works](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55165/17254), but posting a draft that omits authors you know should likely be there doesn't exactly sound like best practice. At a minimum, I'd try to figure the authorship issue out first.

Also keep in mind that people might well *read* your draft. If it looks like a sloppy, incomplete mess or minimally complete work... well, you can guess what impression that'll give. While you're at it,  also guess whether that'll increase or decrease the chances that a semi-interested reader will look at future, more complete preprint and published versions. That is, you want to make sure you're not making it public *too early*. How early is too early ultimately it comes down to a combination of how polished the draft is, how afraid you are of getting scooped, and how important being the absolutely first over the line is. Usually some leeway is given because everyone recognizes that it takes time to do the work and write the paper. If someone posts on the same topic a couple of days late, it will usually be considered an independent discovery.

You might want to consider using this to your advantage by keeping an up-to-date and fairly polished version of the preprint, while finalizing the author list and working on the last pieces. If some other group posts a similar preprint, you can put yours up too quickly enough. If no one does, you can keep polishing the paper and then have a nice work to show the community. On the other hand, if you post an unfinished version, you might well push someone else to post their more polished version.

Also consider reading [Immature papers on arXiv](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/49370/17254) and [What to do when you spot a paper on arXiv with the same essential material as yours?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/27271/17254).